# SPFx extension to redirect user to home page if User doesn't has appropriate permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions

I need to develop and deploy SPFx extension on my site where if the user doesn't have to manage permission and if they want to access site pages they will be redirected to the home page. If anyone could help me redirection code or if its already done share link of GitHub or another link.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

JSOM/Rest API offer some types that could check user's permission:

1. Get current user's permission

[image]

2. Use JSOM to check permission

   function success(data) {
   var permissions = new SP.BasePermissions();
   permissions.fromJson(data.d.EffectiveBasePermissions);
   var hasPermission = permissions.has(SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb);
   }

You can follow below tutorial to connect SPFx with JSOM:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom